# Drools Decision Table - How to use multiple objects in the same condition column

Tags: drools

I have the following POJOs:

1)

```
public class InvoiceDetails{
    String currency;

    public String getCurrency(){
       return this.currency;
    }

    public void setCurrency(String currency){
      this.currency = currency;
    }
}
```

2)

```
public class ValidCurrencies {

    List<String> currencies = new ArrayList<String>();

    public ValidCurrencies() {
        currencies.add("JPY");
        currencies.add("USD");
        currencies.add("EUR");
        currencies.add("CNY");
    }

    public List<String> getCurrencies() {
        return currencies;
    }

    public void setCurrencies(List<String> currencies) {
        this.currencies = currencies;
    }
}
```

I would like to have a condition in my Drools Decision table in the following way:

```
CONDITION                                        |  ACTION
$inv: InvoiceDetails $validCurr: ValidCurrencies |
$param==$validCurr.getCurrencies().containsAll(Arrays.asList($inv.getCurrency()))
TRUE
FALSE
```

Can someone help to write decison tables syntax for writing the following:

- Do action #1 if my Invoice Object contains any `ValidCurrencies`
- Do action #2 if my Invoice Object doesn't contain any `ValidCurrencies`

Comment: Was there ever a solution?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can do it in this way

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>CONDITION</th>
    <th>CONDITION</th>
    <th>CONDITION</th>
    <th>ACTION</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>$inv: InvoiceDetails</td>
    <td>$validCurr: ValidCurrencies</td>
    <td>$param==$validCurr.getCurrencies().contains($inv.getCurrency())</td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>TRUE</td>
    <td>TRUE</td>
    <td>TRUE</td>
    <td>/**action 1**/</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>TRUE</td>
    <td>TRUE</td>
    <td>false</td>
    <td>/**action 2**/</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```